# Wrong size and bytes of decrypted data using AES

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

In our project we use follow methods to encrypt/decrypt important data before storing. Size of incoming bytes is always 32. Please take a look:

```
public static string Encrypt(byte[] data, string pass)
{
    using (var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        var salt = new byte[32];
        new Random().NextBytes(salt);

        using (var rng = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, salt, 3072))
        {
            algorithm.Key = rng.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);
            algorithm.IV = rng.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);

            using (var oms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var ims = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    var encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                    var cs = new CryptoStream(oms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    ims.CopyTo(cs);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                oms.Flush();

                var target = new byte[oms.Length + salt.Length];
                oms.ToArray().CopyTo(target, 0);
                salt.CopyTo(target, oms.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(target);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static byte[] Decrypt(string data, string pass)
{
    var allbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

    var salt = new byte[32];
    var databytes = new byte[allbytes.Length - salt.Length];

    Array.Copy(allbytes, databytes.Length, salt, 0, salt.Length);
    Array.Copy(allbytes, 0, databytes, 0, databytes.Length);

    using (var algorithm = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        using (var rng = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, salt, 3072))
        {
            algorithm.Key = rng.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);
            algorithm.IV = rng.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);

            using (var oms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var ims = new MemoryStream(databytes))
                {
                    var decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ims, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        cs.CopyTo(oms);
                    }
                }

                return oms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works great in all cases. But on customer environment we've got 47 bytes instead of 32 during decryption. After some investigation I realized that such behavior may occurs when use incorrect passphrase (not same as encrypted but good enogth to decrypt in another byte combination). But customer very sure that password is correct. Might be a situation when environmental configuration (Windows or .Net updates, security config etc.) cause such problem?
Thanks for any help.

Upd. Added example code to prove case with incorrect passphrase. Encrypted string contains 32 bytes from 1 to 32 and encrypted with passphrase "p@ssW0rd". If decrypt it using correct passphrase we'll get 32 bytes back, but if use "p4ssW7rd" result will contain 47 bytes.

```
        var password = "p@ssW0rd";
        var incorrectPassword = "p4ssW7rd";
        var encryptedData = "gP/MV6S09UYWc0pMgkkIqEdg204rToV/FQLpvktArWjAlIqjpbiPg5YX9zhPA9/gRuSbNtU5nyBKst54041uGeDNKSYJYvJc1UKZrMcqVFw=";

        var decryptedData = Decrypt(encryptedData, password);
        var incorrectDecryptedData = Decrypt(encryptedData, incorrectPassword);
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted size: {0}, incorrect size: {1}", decryptedData.Length, incorrectDecryptedData.Length);
```

Can be any other case (except incorrect passphrase) to get wrong decrypted data?

Comment: You would get and error if the decryption wasn't correct.  The problem is with following : var target = new byte[oms.Length + salt.Length]; which means one of the lengths is wrong.

Comment: without the decryption code is impossible to tell what's happening.

Comment: @Gusman There is decryption code, please update page

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but I'm sure that lengths are correct. Code works on many other cases

Comment: The code works as expected, your client must be doing something wrong. Does your client really use the code you posted to decrypt the data?

Comment: Also, Do the password contains non-ascii chars? That can be the problem, if there are unicode chars the locale may vary the returned bytes when converting the password string to bytes.

Comment: @Gusman Thanks for answer. Yes, customer use same code for sure, it's clear from our logs. About non-ascii chars in password - might be, but again - customer strongly asserts that uses correct password, I saw it does not contains non-ascii chars

Comment: If you are getting the correct decrypted data than the size of the array is wrong.  Your received data is just getting padded with zeroes at the end.  It is possible the the encrypted algorithm is adding padding that is causing the issue.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but data are incorrect, all 47 bytes are non zero and different from original one

Comment: You can also get back an invalid result if the ciphertext has been corrupted. There is 1/256 chance that either an incorrect password or a corrupted block will **not** throw an exception, due to the nature of PKCS7 padding. For proper security you should also use an HMAC, or better yet use an AEAD cipher like AES-GCM.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thanks for advice that corrupted ciphertext may be one more reason of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES-CBC will happily decrypt to invalid or even random data. Which data depends on both the (wrong) key and the ciphertext. In addition PKCS#7 unpadding doesn't perform any full error detection. It has been created just to make sure that the plaintext consists of 16 byte blocks, as AES can only encrypt 16 bytes at a time (and the CBC mode of operation usually doesn't change that).

So what happens is that for some passwords you may get a key that produces random ciphertext, which, by accident creates valid PKCS#7 padding. The most likely padding is of course a single byte with value `01`, which indicates just one byte of padding, with likelihood 1/256. Then there is two byte padding `0202` but that only has a likelihood of 1/65536, etc.

To solve this situation you should calculate a HMAC over the IV and ciphertext or use an authenticated mode of operation such as GCM. This will catch 100% of the wrong key / ciphertext combinations.

---

So 47 bytes plaintext is 3 * 16 - 1, so you generated a 1 byte padding - the easiest one - by chance. As padding always takes place, 32 bytes of plaintext should indeed be expanded to 48 bytes of ciphertext, with the maximum of 16 bytes of padding (all with value `10` in hex).

Comment: Thanks, looks like password or ciphertext are incorrect in my case